ccwc() function in data.table
I am working on rebuilding the ccwc() function from the Epi package with data.table. Briefly, this function starts from a cohort dataset to build nested case-control dataset. The function mainly allows you to define the time scale to be used (in the example: entry and exit), the number of controls (in the example: 10) to sample and the additional variables to match on (in the example: job). In addition to those, the function creates a column (Set) which is an identifier for each pair case-controls. If more cases have the same date of exit then they belong to the same Set.
Data and packages
#load packages 
library(Epi)
library(data.table)
library(survival)
    
#data
data(diet)
setDT(diet)
setkey(diet,id)

#Rename time columns
diet$entry<-as.numeric(diet$doe-diet$dob)
diet$exit<-as.numeric(diet$dox-diet$dob)

Solution from ccwc() from Epi package
dietcc <- ccwc( entry, exit, chd, controls=10, data=diet,
                include=energy, match=job)

Solution from data.table (my attempt)
My solution is not yet encased as function but the gist is following:
#Select cases and define risk sets
case<-setorder(diet[chd==1], exit,job)[,
                .(id,exitcase=exit,job, event=1,set=rleid(exit,job))][,
                 mult:=.N, by=set]

#Select controls merging them with the cases
control<-diet[case[!duplicated(set,mult),.(id,exitcase,job,mult,set)], 
              .(x.entry, x.exit, x.job, x.id,i.id, mult=i.mult, i.exitcase, i.job),
              on = .( entry <= exitcase,exit > exitcase,job = job),
              by=.EACHI, nomatch=0][,
              .SD[sample(.N, min(10*mult,.N))],by = i.id][ ,set:=rleid(i.id)][,
               .(id=x.id,job=i.job,exitcase=i.exitcase,set,event=0,mult)]

#append controls and cases together
dtcc<-rbind(case,control)
setkey(dtcc,id)

#Include additional predictor (in this case "energy")
dtcc<-dtcc[diet[.(id,energy)], energy := i.energy]

Running models on each dataset

#full cohort
summary(coxph(Surv(as.numeric(doe),as.numeric(dox),chd) ~ scale(energy) + strata(job), data=diet))

#ccwc solution
summary(clogit(formula = Fail ~ scale(energy) + strata(Set), data = dietcc))

#data.table solution
summary(clogit(formula = event ~ scale(energy) + strata(set), data = dtcc))

#Results are very similar

I think my solution is a pretty fast one, especially when the dataset is large. However, when defining the dataset control the non-equi join expands the dataset massively. This will be then reduced in the second statement when sample() is applied.
Do you have any recommendations on making my function more memory efficient? Ideally, I would like to avoid defining case and control dataset separately and run a function on the original dataset (in the example: diet), but I am really struggling to do it!

First of all, I appreciate your answer and way of thinking! I have some suggestions for you.

I think you can use this code:
dtcc <- diet[diet[chd == 1],  on = .(entry <= exit, exit > exitcase, job = job),  allow.cartesian = TRUE][ , .SD[sample(.N, min(10, .N))], by = i.id]
by using [data.table] to avoid separately creating cases and controls,  I would recomend you to use a single join where cases are generated and controls are sampled directly. By leveraging .SD, you could reduce unnecessary memory overhead during sampling.
You can reduce duplication with .I indexing to directly subset only the matched rows without creating intermediate tables, cutting down the memory allocation from duplicated cases/controls. This'll help you:
case_ids <- diet[chd == 1, .I] dtcc <- diet[case_ids][ diet, on = .(entry <= exit, exit > exitcase, job = job), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
We can apply fifelse to conditionally create the event indicator within a single dataset, then we can apply sampling by set within the same workflow. This could potentially reduce rbind calls, improving efficiency.
For instance:
dtcc <- diet[diet[chd == 1, .(id, exitcase = exit, job, set = rleid(exit, job))], on = .(entry <= exitcase, exit > exitcase, job = job),  allow.cartesian = TRUE][, .SD[sample(.N, min(10, .N))], by = .(id, set)][, event := fifelse(id == i.id, 1, 0)] 
We can minimize data size for Non-Equi Joins. When performing non-equi joins, you might choose to keep the dataset lean by limiting it to essential columns (e.g., using data.table’s .SDcols to select only the relevant columns). This will reduce the overhead during the join process. I gave you an example to better understanding:

diet_subset <- diet[, .(id, entry, exit, job, chd)] dtcc <- diet_subset[diet_subset[chd == 1, .(id, exitcase = exit, job, set = rleid(exit, job))],on = .(entry <= exitcase, exit > exitcase, job = job), allow.cartesian = TRUE][, .SD[sample(.N, min(10, .N))], by = .(id, set)]

Wrapping these operations into a single function that directly modifies the original dataset can save memory by avoiding temporary objects. This approach encapsulates the selection, matching, and sampling within a single function call, minimizing the memory footprint as well. I'll give you an example:

`create_ncc_dataset <- function(data, entry, exit, event_var, num_controls = 10, match_var)
{
cases <- data[get(event_var) == 1, .(id, exitcase = get(exit), job = get(match_var),set = rleid(get(exit), get(match_var)))]
controls <- data[cases, on = .(get(entry) <= exitcase, get(exit) > exitcase, job),allow.cartesian = TRUE][, .SD[sample(.N, min(num_controls, .N))], by = .(id, set)]
controls[, event := 0]
cases[, event := 1]
dtcc <- rbind(cases, controls)
return(dtcc)
}
dtcc <- create_ncc_dataset(diet, entry = "entry", exit = "exit", event_var = "chd", num_controls = 10, match_var = "job")`
6)There are also some alternative sampling methods. Instead of sampling 10 times .N (which can be memory-intensive), you can try dynamically adjusting the sample size based on available memory or the size of your dataset.
